# Checking validity of all clojure values in a map

Tags: clojure

Is there a clean, idiomatic way to check that all the values of a map are not empty or 0.

If for instance I have the following map

```
{"id" 10 "Department" "UI Design" "managerid" 4}
```

What's the cleanest way to iterate over the values of the map and make sure the strings are not empty ("") or nil and the ints/longs are not 0 or nil.

Essentially I'm trying to validate some input before I commit it to the DB. I know I could use libraries like Prismatic/schema but for now I'd like to know how it could be achieved without this.

This map only contains strings and ints/longs but it could contain other types.

Is there a generic way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Multimethods](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defmulti) can provide elegant solution for given problem:

```
; for now dispatch is based only on value type
(defmulti valid? (fn [[k v]] (class v)))

(defmethod valid? java.lang.Long [[_ value]] (not (zero? value)))
(defmethod valid? java.lang.String [[_ value]] (not (empty? value)))
(defmethod valid? nil [_] false)
(defmethod valid? :default [_] true) ; valid for rest cases
```

To check whole map:

```
(every? valid? your-map)
```

Examples:

```
(every? valid? {:a 1 :b 0}) ; false
(every? valid? {:a 1 :b 1}) ; true
(every? valid? {:a 1 :b ""}) ; false
(every? valid? {:a 1 :b "a"}) ; true
(every? valid? {:a 1 :b "a" :c []}) ; true
```

Few notes:

- `(not (empty? value))` can be replaced to `(not-empty value)` or `(seq value)`, but in both cases full value of string will be returned instead of boolean (which still will evaluate to `true` of course).
- You cannot check number or string for `nil` because `nil` has its own type. In example above all `nil` values are considered as invalid. If for some keys nils are acceptable - dispatch function `(fn [[k v]] (class v))` should be changed to also take key into account.

This solution is a bit longer than a simple function like

```
(defn valid? [[k v]]
  (cond (string? v) (not (empty? v))
  ...
  :else true))
```

but it is more maintainable and extensible.

**EDIT**. As mentioned in comments, idiomatic way is to use `(seq coll)` instead of `(not (empty? coll))` because [empty?](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5701) is defined like `(not (seq coll))`. You may still want to keep `(not (empty? coll))` check to make validation code more explicit and obvious.

Comment: The [Clojure docs for `empty?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/empty_q) says: "Please use the idiom (seq x) rather than (not (empty? x))", because `(empty? coll)` is defined as `(not (seq coll))`--so `(not (empty? x))` will run `(not (not (seq x)))`.  Some people prefer `(not (empty? x))` anyway, but the official line is that `(seq x)` is the idiomatic way.

Comment: @Mars Thanks. I have added this to the answer.